# Function/Trigger Mutating

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

Is there any way to write after update trigger on the same table for the below problem

Problem statement: whenever the user updates selection column from yes to no with items as 'TV' and id as 1 then selection for the same id and items as 'remote' record should be updated with selection as 'No'

Trigger:

```
Create trigger ttt 
After update on home_items
For each row
Begin
If (new.items = 'TV' AND new.selection = 'No') Then
Update home_items h set h.selection = 'No' where new.id = h.id and h.items = 'Remote';
End If;
End;
```

Error: ORA-04091: table home_items is mutating, trigger/f0unction may not see it

Comment: An update can affect many rows. Your trigger fires per row. Oracle tells you that you cannot read or update the table in your trigger, because the tabe is in the process of changing. You can go about this with a compound trigger where you detect the need to update with the rows and update them after statement.

Answer (score 1):

Use a compound trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER remove_tv_and_remote 
FOR UPDATE ON home_items
COMPOUND TRIGGER
  TYPE ids_type IS TABLE OF HOME_ITEMS.ID%TYPE;
  ids ids_type := ids_type();
AFTER EACH ROW
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF     :new.items     = 'TV'
       AND :new.selection = 'No'
       AND :old.selection = 'Yes'
    THEN
      ids.EXTEND(1);
      ids(ids.COUNT) := :new.id;
    END IF;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;
AFTER STATEMENT
  IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. ids.count
      UPDATE home_items
      SET   selection = 'No'
      WHERE id        = ids(i)
      AND   selection = 'Yes'
      AND   items     = 'Remote';
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE home_items (id, items, selection) AS
SELECT 1, 'TV',     'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'Remote', 'Yes' FROM DUAL;
```

And then do:

```sql
UPDATE home_items
SET   selection = 'No'
WHERE items     = 'TV';
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM home_items;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | ITEMS | SELECTION |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | TV | No |
> | 1 | Remote | No |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1b457c75ef5a56059216540095f4e2f5)*

Answer (score 0):

This infamous `ORA-04091: table ... is mutating` means, Oracle is telling you:
"I cannot guarantee, that what you want is **deterministic**".

Imagine that you run an update on a table `home_items`, this update would modify 2 rows in random order (the order of updates cannot be predicted).

After update of 1st row you execute a trigger, which will see 2nd row as not-modified. And now imagine that due to change of exec plan the order of rows updated is opposite.

There are various ways how to overcome this "problem", many articles were written about this topic. But the root of the problem is determinism of PL/SQL code, Oracle is not smart enough to deduce whether your code is deterministic or not.

PS: in your case you might need just change your trigger into `before update`.

Comment: It is not just being deterministic, but also not entering a kind of loop: the update (or insert/delete) in the trigger is done, it will fire that same trigger again, which may lead to yet another firing and so one, not to talk about constraints, ..... And this problem exists for before and after triggers if they are 'for each row'.

Comment: @gsalem yeah you're right. In this case the update on `home_items` table could be replace by pure assigning into new.selection variable in before trigger.